# ASP.NET MVC DotNetOpenAuth authorization server how-to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth

I have this scenario: a corporate site (MVC 4) and a web shop; add OAuth 2 SSO functionality. Both sites have their own members, but the corp site (for which I'm responsible) must also work as an OAuth 2 authorization server and will store a web shop user id for each member. The shop requested the following endpoints:

**Auth endpoint**

•   authorization:

```
    …/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&state={STATE}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}
```

•   token

```
    …/oauth2/token?code={TOKEN}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&grant_type=authorization_code

    …/oauth2/token?refresh_token={TOKEN}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

**API endpoint**

•   getid (will return JSON with the shop id of the member):

```
    …/oauth2/api/getid?access_token={TOKEN}
```

I don't have experience with OAuth, so I was looking at the DotNetOpenAuth samples and have concluded that I need to implement an [OAuthAuthorizationServer](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/tree/master/src/OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServer), but modifying the sample to fit my requirements is difficult as it seems to do more and is complex.

As researching DotNetOpenAuth seems to be so time consuming, I'd like to ask: is modifying the OAuthAuthorizationServer sample the right approach? Or should I try to make a native implementation or try a different OAuth library that may be easier to use in my situation?

**Please comment on my overall plan:**

-keep the corp site member login flow standard forms auth, straightforward LogOn controller

-add an OAuth controller that will implement the three required endpoints as actions

-when the authorization action is reached, I validate the client and redirect to LogOn passing on the redirect_uri; ***I think the `Authorize` `ActionResult` from `OAuthController.cs` from [the sample](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/blob/master/src/OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServer/Controllers/OAuthController.cs) is where I should start investigating this, and return an `AccountAuthorizeModel`. Is this correct?***

-after the user logs in, and if the login page was reached from the authorization endpoint, I redirect to redirect_uri with the code attached; ***I don't know where to start with this one. `PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest` then `PrepareResponse`? Where does the code come from? Where in the flow should I add a new ClientAuthorization in the database?***

-the shop will then use the code to get or refresh the token, from the /token endpoint; ***simply return `HandleTokenRequest`?***

-with the token the shop site will be able to get the member data JSON; ***have to find out how to validate the token***

Now, besides adding a Clients table to store the client ids and secrets, and ClientAuthorization to keep track of who's authorized, I don't know if the other tables from the DotNetOpenAuth sample are used and when: Nonce, SymmetricCryptoKey, User.

Modifying OAuth2AuthorizationServer.cs seems straightforward, I only have to add real certificates and make sure the clients are pulled from my data context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are right in most of the points. Let's comment them:

- OAuth server should have 2 endpoints (not 3), as requesting token and refreshing token goes to the same endpoint (TokenEndpoint).
- It depends if your are going to implement a different authentication server (or controller), or you are going to implement the authentication responsibility inside the authorization server. In case they are separated, the authentication server should be the one responsible of displaying the logon, authenticate and communicate with authorization server using OpenID protocol (Also supported by DotNetOpenAuth).
- Once the user is authenticated, the authorization server should store the data of the user identity somehow, and return the authorization code (if using this Oauth flow) using DotNetOpenAuth functions:

  > var response =
  >   this.AuthServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(AuthorizationRequest,
  >   User.Identity.Name);
  >       return this.AuthServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(response);
  >                        finalResponse.AsActionResult();

I don't think you need to save nothing about the authorization process in the database, and the code is generated by DotNetOpenAuth and sent to the client into the query string of the redirection.

- Then, the client should get the code (ProcessUserAuthorization) and call the TokenEndpoint. This endpoint is just returning HandleTokenRequest, that internally is calling to some OAuthAuthorizationServer functions, such as CreateAccessToken.
- Once the client has the access token, it should call the resources, sending the token into the HTTP Header 'Authorization'. The resource server is the responsible to validate the token.

  > var resourceServer = new ResourceServer(new
  >   StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer(signing, encrypting));
  >
  > ```
  >  AccessToken token = resourceServer.GetAccessToken(request, scopes);
  > ```

A store provider for nonce and crytoKeys is needed using this flow. Have a look to class InMemoryCryptoKeyStore in:

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios

Hope this helps!